# Lowest Memory Cache Method for PHPExcel

Tags: benchmarking, phpexcel

I tried using the different caching methods in section 4.2.1 of PHPExcel manual.

did a benchmark with 100k rows and here are the results

```
gzip = time=50,memoryused=177734904
ser  = time=34,memoryused=291654272
phptm= time=41,memoryused=325973456
isamm= time=39,memoryused=325972824
```

the manual says that the phptmp and isamm methods use disk instead of memory. Hence, they should use the least memory, but it seems that this was the opposite.

Here is the code I used to test:

```
                $cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory::cache_in_memory_gzip;
//              $cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory::cache_in_memory_serialized;
//              $cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory:: cache_to_phpTemp;
//          $cacheSettings = array( 'memoryCacheSize'  => '8MB');               
//              $cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory:: cache_to_discISAM;

                PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod, $cacheSettings);

                $xlsReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($fileType);
                $xlsReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
```

Anyone can shed light on this mystery?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This depends on many factors including PHP version, content of cells (numeric, string, rich text, etc), extensions enabled for PHP, etc; so it is impossible for anybody other than yourself to actually answer, because it is unique for your situation.

However, all methods retain some information about each cell in memory, with the exception of SQLite, so using an SQLite database is the most memory efficient option.

**EDIT**

I ran some tests with different caching methods against different versions of PHP some months ago, and the following summarises the results

[image]

[image]

These are still fairly arbitrary result, disk speed and other factors will affect performance for some caching methods like discisam and phptemp, and any configuration settings for options like phptemp will also have some affect; but it should give a relative guideline for working out which options are better for memory, and which are better for speed of execution.

Comment: As a general rule for servers that don't care about execution time but have memory limits, would you recommend using SQLite3 as the best option?

Comment: Where SQLite3 is an option, and memory is an issue (and the slower execution speed is not a problem), then yes, I would recommend using SQLite3 caching